# Write file even if output css is empty

Tags: css, gruntjs, minify

I want to write an empty file even the destination file is empty.

Is it possible?

The error I get is "destination not written because minified css was empty".

I'm using `grunt-contrib-cssmin` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only using `grunt-contrib-cssmin`, you cannot.

A good place to start when wondering about something specific to a piece of open source software: the source code itself — the task is only ~70 lines. From [the source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/blob/v0.9.0/tasks/cssmin.js#L49-L51) we can see the "error" you're getting:

```
if (min.length === 0) {
    return grunt.log.warn('Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.');
}
```

You might want to look into "touching" the file. If you are familiar with *nix, you'll know that touch will create the file if it doesn't exist and **not** truncate it if it does. In Grunt (node.js) you might want to look into [`node-touch`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-touch) or [`grunt-exec`](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec).

As for your `Gruntfile`, you'd need only **one** of the following two tasks:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var touch = require('touch');
    grunt.initConfig({
        'cssmin': {
            'combine': {
                'files': { 'path/to/output.css': ['path/to/input_one.css', 'path/to/input_two.css'] }
            }
        },
        'exec': {
            'touch': { 'command': 'touch path/to/output.css' }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
    grunt.registerTask('touch', touch.sync.bind(undefined, 'path/to/output.css'));
    grunt.registerTask('minifycss1', ['cssmin', 'exec:touch']); // 1
    grunt.registerTask('minifycss2', ['cssmin', 'touch']);      // 2
};
```

1. Uses [`grunt-exec`](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec).
2. Uses [`node-touch`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-touch).

Comment: Thx Whymarrh. I'm not very familiar with grunt "world", I didn't know where the task's were. I've comment that statement and it works the way I want.